# Converting CSV file of WKT data to shapefile using QGIS 2.01

Tags: shapefile, convert, qgis-2, latitude-longitude, well-known-text

Is it possible to create a shapefile directly from a CSV WKT file in QGIS 2.01?

```
WKT
POLYGON(...)
POLYGON(...)
```

Save as shapefile doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Save as should work. What exactly happens if you try? Can you provide a few lines of the CSV for test purposes?

Comment: Ok: wkt_geom WKT Indicator Unit Subgroup Area Area ID Time Perio Source Data Value Total ug_dis_txt ug_dis_t_1 ug_dis_t_2 ug_dis_t_3 ug_dis_t_4
NULL  Rural safe water coverage Percent Total Kasese AFRUGA004006 1997 UGA_SA01, Statistical Abstract for the Year 2001, Uganda Bureau of Statistics_June 2001 56.8 56.8 MULTIPOLYGON (((29.69894176319956 -0.207959707995483,29.699173391560674 -0.207610084667762,29.69928899695746 -0.207609762601961,29.699288480121101 -0.207610802690738,29.69894176319956 -0.207959707995483)),((30.289259452112795 0.230890259465728,30.2895114 120 Pre 2005 0.274835 2.477278

Comment: THis is only one line.. I cannot post most characters :)

Comment: You can edit this into your question. The header line should be seperate. Otherwise you have a line separation problem, which might be Operating System dependent. What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSV import with WKT, the delimiter **must** be semicolon or tab, because comma and blank are already used inside the WKT field as point and coordinate separators.

You can exchange the separators with a good text editor (like Notepad++ on Windows).

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it by opening as delimited file and than save as shapefile.. I have to learn a lot :), installed QGis only a few day ago. Thanks!

Comment: I am also new to the GIS stack exchange, how should I close a question after it is solved?

Comment: @TimTensen There is a tick mark button besides every answer which you can use to "accept" the answer which solved your problem.