# Lat/Long data to shapefile with many values in CSV dataset

Tags: qgis, coordinates, latitude-longitude, well-known-text, polygon-creation

I have my polygon spatial data in a format of CSV with the column of lat/long delimited by comma. Is there any way to upload this csv and got polygon shapefiles (or any other visualisable format)? My primary GIS tool is QGIS.

There are several ways how to do it just for one WKT at the same time but I cannot find a way how to do it with data with several rows in data.

I have tried to Add delimited text layer with geometry definition of WKT but it does not work (as can be seen in the screenshot. Data are not in the readable WKT format.

I am up to some solution even outside QGIS environment

Comment: you must use semicolon or tab for importing https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82549/how-can-i-convert-a-csv-file-of-wkt-data-to-a-shapefile-using-qgis-2-01

Comment: please don't post pictures of your data, it makes it very hard to read and parse

Comment: @IanTurton data deleted. I just posted a screenshot to show and approximate how they might look

Comment: the idea was good but a picture is not - so please add an actual sample of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume there is a `.csv`-file with your data, where lat/long delimited by comma, see image below

[image: csv]

1. Drag&Drop your CSV into QGIS

   [image: input]
2. Deploy Virtual Layers through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.
   In the Query window just simply paste the following expression:

   ```sql
   SELECT *, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || "coord_values" || '))', #putyourSRIDcodehere) AS geom
   FROM "polygons"
   ```

   P.S. Mind the [SRID code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system#Identifier)
3. And get the output

   [image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Visualising WKT geometry string in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/visualising-wkt-geometry-string-in-qgis)

Comment: The data that OP has seem to lack the duplicates of the first vertices as closing vertices  and "coord_values" can't be just slipped inside WKT polygon. Perhaps they must be flipped inside linestring instead and  converted into polygons with some other operation.